# Conditionally disable asset precompile in Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've seen various convoluted and generally ineffective solutions to performing lazy asset precompile in Rails. As a backend developer I don't particularly want to recompile assets I never touch every time the program deploys, but because assets are loaded in `Capfile` via `load 'deploy/assets'`, and not by defining a task in `deploy.rb`, I can't think of a way to conditionally disable it.

The behaviour I'm after is to use `cap deploy` for regular with-precompile deployment, and to use `cap deploy:no_assets` to skip asset deployment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**rails4** addresses this issue with it's new version of sprockets, by only precompiling assets that have changed. In the mean time, for your **rails3** apps I recommend the [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) gem.

This gem started out as a [set of patches](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/21) for `sprockets-rails` by Nathan Broadbent, which were not merged into `master` because the problem was already addressed in rails4. From the README:

> - Speeds up your Rails 3 rake assets:precompile by only recompiling changed assets, based on a hash of their source files
> - Only compiles once to generate both fingerprinted and non-fingerprinted assets

And:

> turbo-sprockets-rails3 should work out of the box with the latest version of Capistrano.

I can confirm that it works well for me on rails-3.2.x apps deploying with Capistrano.

*As a side note for GitHubbers, the original [pull request](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/21) is an excellent example of how to submit code to an open source project, even if it wasn't merged.*

Comment: Just switched to this myself and can attest its great!

Comment: I do have Rails 4.0 and I do not change any assets but it simply recompiles everything from scratch. Any idea?

Answer (score 15):

Both turbo-sporocket-rails and the that auto-skip scripts have some pitfalls (I will mention later). So I use the following hack, so I can pass a parameter to skip asset pre-compile at my will:

```
callback = callbacks[:after].find{|c| c.source == "deploy:assets:precompile" }
callbacks[:after].delete(callback)
after 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:assets:precompile' unless fetch(:skip_assets, false)
```

This script will change the built-in asset-precompile hook, so it will be hooked based on the **skip_assets** parameter. I can call `cap deploy -S skip_assets=true` to skip asset precompile as a whole.

---

For me, turbo-sporocket-rails still takes minutes to do the checking when nothing has changed. This can be crucial when I need to push a fix to the server asap. Therefore I need my force-skipping method.

Comment: This is a great solution. On a Rails 4 app with Capistrano 2 and it still works. Just gotta be careful that you don't have any other jobs chained off of 'deploy:assets:precompile' or they will be skipped too.

Answer (score 1):

This gist looks very promising https://gist.github.com/3072362

It checks your git log from the last deploy to now to see if there are any changes in `%w(app/assets lib/assets vendor/assets Gemfile.lock config/routes.rb)` and if so, only precompiles then.

Comment: I've installed this gist and ones similar to it before, but it doesn't seem to have had any effect. If I leave `load 'deploy/assets'` in my capfile, it doesn't stop precompile when not needed. If i take out `load 'deploy/assets'`, it doesn't precompile even when it needs to.

Even with an added trigger to fire it after code update.

Comment: I think it's possible you aren't requiring this gist in your config/deploy.rb file. It overwrites the deploy:assets:precompile task. You should keep `load 'deploy/assets'` in your Capfile.

Comment: This is still faster than turbo-sporocket-rails, since it skips the entire checking, which take minutes for me.